# Python Sympy solve returns list vs. dictionary

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy and its solve function, but I noticed that it sometimes returns a dictionary in a list but in other cases just a dictionary, without a list.

```
from sympy import * 
x, y = symbols('x y')
q = 16*x**0.5*y**0.5
solve((diff(q, x)/5 - diff(q, y)/20, 3200 - q))
```

This returns a list: [{x: 400.000000000000, y: 100.000000000000}]

```
x, y = symbols('x y')
q = 8*x**.5*y**0.5
solve((diff(q, x)/10 - diff(q, y)/8, 400-10*x-8*y))
```

This returns a dictionary, without a list: {x: 20.0000000000000, y: 25.0000000000000}

Why does this happen? Thank you for your help.

Comment: So there's no clue in the `solve` docs?  I see a `dict=True` flag mentioned.  And lots of examples, but don't have time now to read the docs in detail.

Comment: The `solve` function is inconsistent like this. The `dict=True` parameter can be used to get a consistent return type.

Comment: Simply adding a power to the 2nd equation in the 2nd case (e.g. `x**2`) produces a list of dict.  My guess that without the powers, the 2nd case is simpler to solve, and it takes a different path, with a different return statement.  That probably can only be verified by reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

This does not explain why it happens, but it provides a way of handling the result, whatever that is.
I was using the results of solving in later `.subs`, in several instances (copy-pasted from an original one), and some failed due to the non-uniform type of output from `sympy.solve`.
So I used

```
Csol = sympy.solve((sympy.Eq(myeq, 0)), (C1, C2), dict=True)
Csol = Csol[0] if type(Csol) is list else Csol
```

This way, `Csol` always contains a `dict`, and

```
myeq.subs(Csol)
```

always works.

Answer (score -1):

And explanation of output types [has been added](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/doc/src/explanation/solve_output.rst) to the documentation. The gist is given in that exaplanation's opening paragraph:

> The reasons for this are historical and are biased toward human
> interaction rather than programmatic use. The type of output will
> depend on the type of equation(s) (and how they are entered) and the
> number of symbols that are provided (and how they are provided).

`solve` has two main pathways: single equations vs multiple equations. For each of those the user may accept any solution (by not providing symbols) or give the symbols of interest. The treatment of the equation(s) can also depend on whether the system is linear or not.